# Does OmniAuth support signing OAuth requests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, oauth, omniauth

I know OmniAuth is excellent at helping you authenticate with the Twitter API, but can it also help with other things related to OAuth?

Specifically, I'm trying to create authorization headers to use when making API calls, ie:

```
Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="CONSUMER_KEY",
oauth_nonce="5851be947bed841b6464e4328A9a3fdb1",
oauth_signature="lsRs5YSb53yiiZi9HGlRsGXG0Y8%3DA", 
oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", 
oauth_timestamp="1398648488", 
oauth_token="OAUTH_TOKEN", 
oauth_version="1.0"
```

And am wondering why this process seems needlessly difficult. Creating a signature as described here https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/creating-signature is a standardized process, and it seems like OmniAuth or an OAuth gem should be able to do this... but I haven't been able to find anything.

Can anyone provide additional insight on how these steps are typically handled?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you referring to different OAuth providers or signing the API requests? With OmniAuth there are strategies that people have created for the different providers. As for signing you can use something like httparty and make the request and put the token in the header.

Comment: Signing the API requests. I am using httparty to put the token in the header, but need something to create that header for each user. Ie: generate the nonce, signature, incorporate the users token, etc. Are there any utilities or solutions to do that?

Comment: Usually after a oauth authorization you get a token and a secret, ther e is no need to generate a nonce or signature as the omniauth gem takes care of that for you.

Comment: There isn't to authenticate with your Twitter credentials -- OmniAuth is certainly handling that process. But what about when I want to make API calls? Ie: '    HTTParty.get "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json", 
      {
        query: {
          q: keywords
        },
        headers: {
          "Authorization" => authorization
        }
      }'. Or is there another way to make this call with OmniAuth instead of HTTParty?

Comment: OmniAuth is just for the initial authorization and the retrieval of access keys, this is where HTTParty comes into play. Is there a reason why you don't want to use a Twitter gem?

Comment: It's for a coding challenge (for an interview) so I feel like using the Twitter gem might be inappropriate. I actually am very close and have all the parts calculating and producing headers similar to what comes out of the Twitter OAuth tool, but am still recieving '215 bad authentication data' errors when making the calls. I'm using a process similar to the one described here: https://gist.github.com/erikeldridge/383159

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51633/discussion-between-kyle-chadha-and-john)